# Wordpress - Add a new class to an element on same template-page.php depending the active page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I create a custom template "page-products.php" for all my products page.

Inside of this template, i have a horizontal menu with 8 items.
[example capture of the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqDyD.png)

When i'm on the page of the current product, i would change the back-ground color of the element menu.

Any ideas to add a new class on an element when on the current page ?

I would like to avoid to create 8 differents template for each different product.

Comment: do you want to randomly change the background color of the element? or is there any specific requirements?

Comment: I don't want to change it randomly. I need to have a specific color (darker) for the active element corresponding to the active page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your theme uses body_class() on the body – you can style from the body class down to the element. In my example .page-8 is on the body-tag and .menu would be the menu.

```
.page-8 .menu {background-color: red;}
```

Comment: Brilliant ! My theme uses this function - and it seems to work great ! Thanks a lot ! I didn't know about this function !